# Pegar variável PHP e exibir no input

Tags: php, html

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou querendo pegar o valor da variavel cpf, depois que ela for tratada, e exibi-lá dentro de um input.

praticando.php

```
    <fieldset style="width:50%; margin: 0px auto; ">
        <legend>Colocando PONTO no CPF</legend>
        <form method="POST" action="validaPraticando.php">
            <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
            <input type="number" name="cpf" placeholder="Sem pontos e traço" required />
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="button"/><br/><br/>
            <input name='recebe' value="QUERO_EXIBI-LA_AQUI" readonly style='width:100%;'/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
```

validaPraticando.php

```
<?php
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$campoRecebe = $_POST['recebe'];

if(strlen($cpf) == 11){
    $pegaCpf = substr($cpf,0,3).'.'.substr($cpf,3,3).'.'.substr($cpf,6,3).'-'.substr($cpf,9,2);
    echo $pegaCpf;
}else{
    echo "CPF inválido";
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Tem conhecimento sobre requisições assíncronas (AJAX)?

Comment: Não tenho. Pode fazer uma breve explicaçao? Aí dou uma pesquisada sobre o assunto.

Comment: Tem conhecimento de Jquery ?

Comment: Não tenho RickPariz. Vou dar um pesquisada sobre o assunto.

Comment: Vou dar uma resposta utilizando`jquery` e `ajax`, vou tentar ser bem simples e te explicar direitinho

Comment: @GuilhermeWayne, caso a minha resposta te ajude, e seja a certa, não esqueça de marca-la como a solução, para que outros membros da comunidade, saibam que está pergunta está fechada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto é uma coisa bem simples de se fazer, utilizando requisições assíncronas (ajax), bom vamos lá..

Ajax é o uso do objeto XMLHttpRequest para se comunicar com os scripts do lado do servidor. Oque torna o `ajax` uma ótima ferramenta, são suas requisições assíncronas,  o que significa que ele pode fazer tudo isso sem a necessidade de atualizar a página.

Isto é justamento oque você quer, o formulário será enviado, e o valor do cpf aparecerá em um `input` após a sua validação. Isso sem atualizar a pagina, para não ocorrer perca de dados e etc.

Você pode ler mais sobre `ajax` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Para usar `ajax`, é muito comum as pessoas utilizarem uma biblioteca `javascript` chamada `jquery`. Ela é uma biblioteca que nós como desenvolvedores web, temos a obrigação de conhecer, ela facilita muito a nossa vida.

Você pode ler mais sobre `jquery` [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/jquery-introducao-e-primeiros-passos/21047).

Bom vamos ao código !

> OBS: não esqueça de importar o jquery no fim da página !

O Html

```
<fieldset style="width:50%; margin: 0px auto; ">
        <legend>Colocando PONTO no CPF</legend>
        <form id="form">
            <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
            <input type="number" name="cpf" placeholder="Sem pontos e traço" required />
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="button"/><br/><br/>
            <input name='recebe' id="recebe" value="QUERO_EXIBI-LA_AQUI" readonly style='width:100%;'/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
```

Não existe a necessidade de colocar `attrs` como `action` e `method` na `tag form`, já que iremos utilizar `ajax`. 
Se você observar eu coloquei um `id` `form` e também no `input` que receberá o cpf formatado, isso foi feito para que possamos encontrar o `input` correto na hora de colocar o valor com `jquery`

JavaScript

vamos começar com a function `ready` do `jquery`, ela diz o seguinte: " Após o documento (página) ser carregada, execute está função..

Sintaxe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // tudo que estiver aqui poderá ser executado, após o documento ser carregado
});
```

Vamos continuar..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // tudo que estiver aqui poderá ser executado, após o documento ser carregado

  $("#form").on("submit", function(e){
    // está função diz, que quando esse formulario for enviado, tudo oque estiver aqui será executado.
    e.preventDefault(); // está função é usada pro form não ir para outra pagina, pois o evento padrão de um formulario é ir para outra pagina.
    var data = $("#form").serialize(); // a function serialize serve para pegar todos os valores que foram colocados nos inputs do form
    $.ajax({
      // está é a função ajax, do jquery, ela será usada para fazer a requisição assícrona.
      url: "validaPraticando.php", // aqui vai a url da requisição, nela é colocado o valor do atributo action da tag form
      data:  data, // aqui vai os dados para o servidor, geralmente é os inputs do form
      method: "POST", // aqui vai o método da requisição, acho que você já sabe sobre o get e post !
      dataType: "json", // aqui será o tipo de resposta que vamos receber, será no formato json, um formato simples e mais usado.
      success: function(data){
        // essa é a function success, ela ira ser executada se a requisição for feita com sucesso
        $("#retorno").val(data); // aqui estamos setando o valor retornado do php, no input
         // a variavel data, veio do parametro da function, e será a resposta do php.
      },
      error: function(){
        // essa é funcion error, ela será executada caso ocorrer algum erro na requisição
        alert("erro na requisição");
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Por fim, o php.. 
Ele será exatamente como está, oque irá mudar é a forma que você irá retornar o cpf.

```
<?php
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

if(strlen($cpf) == 11){
    $pegaCpf = substr($cpf,0,3).'.'.substr($cpf,3,3).'.'.substr($cpf,6,3).'-'.substr($cpf,9,2);
    echo json_encode($pegaCpf);
}else{
    echo json_encode("CPF Invalido");
}
  ?>
```

Para devolvermos respostas no formato `json` (é o formato que setamos na requisição `ajax`) é comum usarmos a function `json_encode(data)`.

Espero ter ajudado ! No começo, pode parecer muito confuso essas coisas.. `jquery`, `ajax`, `json` e etc.. mas você verá que é muito simples e fácil de se aprender.

Comment: Valeu mesmo RickPariz, ajudou muito. Vou estudar bastante sobre o assunto. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta acima é muito boa e funcionará perfeitamente. Caso sua ideia for algo mais simples, pois pelo que entendi você está iniciando seus estudos, você pode colocar todos os dados em uma pagina só

praticando.php :

```
<?php

        if (isset($_POST['cpf'])) {
            $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

            if(strlen($cpf) == 11){
                $pegaCpf = substr($cpf,0,3).'.'.substr($cpf,3,3).'.'.substr($cpf,6,3).'-'.substr($cpf,9,2);

            }else{
                echo "CPF inválido";
            }
        }

  ?>


<fieldset style="width:50%; margin: 0px auto; ">
    <legend>Colocando PONTO no CPF</legend>
    <form method="POST" action="praticando.php">
        <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
        <input type="number" name="cpf" placeholder="Sem pontos e traço" required />
        <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="button"/><br/><br/>
          <?php
            if (isset($_POST['cpf'])) {
            echo"<input name='recebe' value='" + $pegaCpf + "' readonly style='width:100%;'/>"
            }
            else{
                echo"<input name='recebe' value='CPF inválido' readonly style='width:100%;'/>"
            }
          ?>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Mas lembrando que isso so funciona para seus estudos.

Comment: Valeu Luiz Santos, obrigado pela dica.